# Caught a null exception: possible?

Tags: android, exception, android-emulator, adt

I'm trying to run this [Android OCCI client](https://github.com/r2ad/R2AD-Android-Cloud-Client) from source code. I cannot login as I get a `null` Exception that I can't debug. The guilty method is the following:

```
protected HttpResponse getResponse(String url) {
    HttpResponse result = null;
    try {           
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String username = getAccount().getUsername();           
        if (username != null && username.length() > 0) {
            httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope(null, -1),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, getAccount().getUserToken()));
            Log.d(toString(), "Using Credentials " + username + " " + getAccount().getUserToken());
        } 
        HttpGet get = generateHeader(url);
        HttpResponse httpResp = httpclient.execute(get); //BOOM
        int response = httpResp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        Log.d(toString(), url + " HttpResponse is " + response);
        if (response == 200 || response == 204) {
            result = httpResp;
        } 
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Log.e("CloudServiceAdapter","Error connecting", t); /I inserted this
    } 
    return result;      
}
```

Originally, the catch block did nothing. I added a log statement but I only get "Error connecting" as output. The debugger says that `t` is `null`, which is impossible in Java. I tried to change `Throwable` to `Exception` but same. There are other questions related to this problem, but none helped.

The only interesting warning from the log is

```
09-18 09:17:27.642: W/dalvikvm(1113): VFY: unable to resolve static method 1818: Lorg/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64;.encodeBase64String ([B)Ljava/lang/String;
```

I tried to configure build path, check all JARs in "Order and export" (they are inside /libs in the project directory), but didn't work.

I read that external JARs must be processed by `dx`, [**but**](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/index.html) Eclipse ADT is supposed to run it by itself.

Any ideas?

Comment: silly question: do you have the internet permission?

Comment: Do you use ProGuard or any other obfuscation tool? If yes may be ProGuard has removed the encodeBase64String(..) method in it's optimization phase.

Comment: @blackbelt too obvious: I do. I believe the original developers tested the tool at least once :D Anyway I just verified the manifest on github https://github.com/r2ad/R2AD-Android-Cloud-Client/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @Robert no proguard.cfg file present. Actually that's an open source project

Comment: @djechelon I use ProGuard also in open source projects. With disabled obfuscation you can minimize the final JAR size by removing unused classes and methods. I often see a reduction of about often 30-50%.

Comment: But @Robert you that you are more expert than me can confirm that there PG is disabled by simply looking at the Git link at the top of message and see there is no proguard.cfg in the project. Or am I wrong about it?

Comment: It seems to me an issue with the java verifyer. Maybe are you missing up something with external libray  (apache commons)?